# Cannot attach shared memory in shared library

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, shared-memory

I would like to use shared memory in shared library to data exchange and operate socket.
In my library, when first process loads shared libary, shared memory is created in constructor.
Then, second process load shared library,  I want to attach this shared memory.
But second process create other shared memory although key is same.

This is sample code.

```c
char* sharedmemory;

__attribute__ ((constructor)) void attach_sharedmemory() {
    key_t key = 10;
    errno = 0
    int seg_id = shmget(key, 1000, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0660);
    if(seg_id == -1){
        if(errno == EEXIST){
            seg_id = shmget(key, 0, 0);
            if(seg_id == -1){
                exit(1);
            }else{
                shared_memory = (char*)(shmat(seg_id, 0, 0));
            }
        }else{
            exit(1);
        }
    }else{
        shared_memory = (char*)(shmat(seg_id, 0, 0));
    }
}

void dllfunction1(){}
void dllfunction2(){}
```

`ipcs` command result is here.
Second process shmid is always first process's shmid + 1.

```
#result of ipcs
------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid owner perms bytes nattch status
0x00000XXX 65536 user1 660   1000     1    dest  <--- created first process
0x00000YYY 65537 user1 660   1000     1    dest  <--- created second process
```

How can I fix this?

My enviroment is Ubuntu 20.04LTS.
Compiled GCC.

Comment: did you try the version below?

Comment: Thank you! Thank you very much for your kind answer. Yes, it worked in one machine. But in another machine,(this is the machine I want to use), problem was not solved in spite of same code. I tried again and again and checked code. But  not solved... How can I do?

Comment: Welcome.  Different OS or revisions on the 2 machines? Try running `strace` or a debugger and view return values and errno after `shmget()` and `shmat()`.  See `ipcs -m` and `ipcrm -m`. Also try all `shmget()` without IPC_EXCL.

Comment: Than you very much. Yes. Successed one in Ubuntu on WSL. Failed one is real Ubuntu. Ok. I will try your advice. And very unfortunately, I cannot try to your advise for 5 days due to my privete reasen. So, maybe Oct 22, I will answer the result. Thanky you a lot! You are very kind person!

Comment: Yes, I succced. I missee my code! Thank you very very much! I appreciate a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The second process calling `shmget()` fails due to the flag bit IPC_EXCL
as expected; although the next call to `shmget()` reused the same key and
flags changed to 0 (no IPC_EXCL), the size was 0 leading to a new segment.

By reusing the same key *and* size (again flags without IPC_EXCL), the second
process can get the same segment ID and attach.  Sample code below is
based on the original with added shmem detach:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

static void *sharedmemory;
static int seg_id;

__attribute__ ((constructor))
void attach_shmem(void)
{
    key_t key = 10;
    size_t size = 1000;
    seg_id = shmget(key, size, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0660);

    if ((seg_id == -1) && (errno == EEXIST))
        seg_id = shmget(key, size, 0);
    if (seg_id == -1)
        exit(1);
    sharedmemory = shmat(seg_id, NULL, 0);
}

__attribute__ ((destructor))
void detach_shmem(void)
{
    (void) shmdt(sharedmemory);
}
```

Comment: Note that calling `printf()` can change the value of `errno` so you need to save it **before** you call `printf()` and use that value.

Comment: test stuff trimmed